# jQuery Datepicker Choosing Return Date

Tags: jquery, datepicker

I have a from date and to date. I want the todate to start with the day fromdate is chosen. For example: if I choose from date to be 7th Jan, 2015, I want the datepicker to show the todate from 7th Jan, 2015 onwards and not anything before that. How do I achieve it?

```
<script type="text/javascript">
      $(document).ready(function(){
           $("#from_date").datepicker({
               maxDate: -1,
               minDate: "2015-01-01",
               dateFormat:"yy-mm-dd"
            });
            $("#to_date").datepicker({
               maxDate: -1,
               minDate: "2015-01-01",
               dateFormat:"yy-mm-dd"
            });
      });
    </script>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$(function() {
    $( "#from" ).datepicker({
        changeMonth: true,
        onClose: function( selectedDate ) {
            $( "#to" ).datepicker( "option", "minDate", selectedDate );
        }
    });
    $( "#to" ).datepicker({
        changeMonth: true,
        onClose: function( selectedDate ) {
            $( "#from" ).datepicker( "option", "maxDate", selectedDate );
        }
    });
});
```

**[Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/zguzkstr/1/)**.